# Decoding WAV Files in Squeak Smalltalk

Tags: audio, wav, smalltalk, squeak

I am working on a small project in Squeak and have ran into a problem: I can't get WAV files to decode correctly.

Here's the two methods I am using to decode it at the moment:

```
convert4bitUnsignedTo16Bit: anArray
    "Convert the given array of samples--assumed to be 4-bit unsigned, linear data--into 16-bit signed samples. Return an array containing the resulting samples. I only thinking it is unsigned. I don't really know."
| n samples s |
n _ anArray size.
samples _ SoundBuffer newStereoSampleCount: (n * 2).
1 to: n do: [:i |
    s _ anArray at: i.
    samples at: (i * 2) put: (self imaDecode: s).
    samples at: ((i * 2) - 1) put: (self imaDecode: s)].
^ samples
```

.

```
imaDecode: number
| n |
n _ number.
n >= 128 ifTrue: [n _ n - 256].
^ (n) * 16
```

It gives me a sound at the correct rate, and if I listen closely, I can hear the original sound. But it is very staticy.

I am wondering if anyone can spot what is wrong with my code and help me figure out why the sound is so staticy. (BTW: I would call the `convert4bitUnsignedFrom16Bit:` method from the `readFrom:` method in SampledSound with the `data` variable as the argument).

-TheCompModder

Answer (score 5):

The input to your decoder method is a `ByteArray`. Each 8-bit byte stores two samples in a 4-bit encoding. Assuming this is a stereo track then the left/right channel would be stored in each byte's upper/lower 4 bits. Your `imaDecode:` method does not extract those bits. I think it should look more like this (obviously untested):

```
1 to: n do: [:i |
    byte := anArray at: i.
    left := byte bitAnd: 15.                 "lower 4 bits"
    right := (byte >> 4) bitAnd: 15.         "upper 4 bits"
    samples at: (i * 2) put: (left - 8) << 12.
    samples at: ((i * 2) - 1) put: (right - 8) << 12].
```

This would put the 4-bit values into `left` and `right`, bias them by `-8` (assuming they're actually signed) and expand by 12 bits to be a full 16 bit signed sample.

Btw I think your buffer size is too large, its `stereoSampleCount` should be `n` not `n * 2`.

Also, you might want to post a sample file to the Squeak developers mailing list if you need further help.